# Gmail API Credit Card Information

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-cloud-console

Is it possible to use the Free Trial on Google Cloud Platform to enable Gmail API,  without providing Credit Card information? 
I am trying to enable Gmail API for sending Emails through an Email address procured under GSuite prior 2012.
Please Advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free trial on Google cloud platform requires that you enter a credit card information to use it.

The gmail api is part of the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) which should not require that you have a google cloud platform account to access it.   You should be able to login to that and create your project and credentials and enable the gmail api their.